# How to reorder automatically generated methods in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, generated-code

When using Netbeans' features for generating event handlers from a GUI, for example, while the body of the generated methods are editable, I cannot find a way to change the order of the generated methods within the code of a class.

Cutting for cutting and pasting is not allowed with generated code.

How instead might I do this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that in Netbeans. It's not really a priority because you can use the Navigator instead.

If you really want to move those blocks, open the Java file with an other editor (Gedit, Notepad...) and re-order the blocks here.

You can also remove the `//GEN-FIRST` and `//GEN-LAST` to make them editable in Netbeans.