# Netbeans history shows 100 changes but I made only a few. How do I avoid this?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ide, generated-code

In Netbeans when I make a dozen changes that break more than they fix, usually I find the culprit right away by looking at the history, find the culprit, fix it, and go on my merry way. Takes very little time.

But often I find that Netbeans shows nearly 100 changes. Almost all of them involve changes like the two pairs of history lines below (older line listed first in each pair):

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          


// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
// </editor-fold>
```

The vast majority of the changes seem to only occur on statements generated by Swing design.

Why do `//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents` and `//GEN-END:initComponents` get added onto lines I didn't change?

What did I do to cause this?

How can I avoid this? (Other than quit using Swing design, which I already have in other projects, but this is an older project that I'm sort of stuck with.)

What can I do to fix it so I can just see the lines I changed?

I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009940/how-to-reorder-automatically-generated-methods-in-netbeans) but it doesn't tell *how* "You can also remove the //GEN-FIRST and //GEN-LAST to make them editable in Netbeans."

Comment: The folded code is regenerated based on properties _each_ time you build.

Comment: @trashgod--Please let me make sure I understand: (1) this will happen ONLY to the class files designed in Swing builder AND (2) it will happen to them EVERY time I rebuild the project and so this is (3) just one more reason to avoid Swing builder. Am I right?

Comment: @trashgod--One last thought: All I really need to do is just MOVE into a different class file all the modules that COULD be placed elsewhere and make sure include as little as possible likely-to-change logic in the Swing-built class file. Meanwhile, just pan down to look for the blue arrows indicating MY changes, which is still a pain, but I guess it's the price I'll pay until I revamp the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The folded code is regenerated, based on GUI editor properties, *each* time you build; the effect you describe is not unexpected. Alter a specific property, e.g. by using the `Customize Code…` dialog, and see how the generated code changes. While the source code editor can collapse generated code, the history views cannot.

Some mitigation strategies:

- Limit use of the GUI editor to the relatively small number of enclosing containers that really need it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2561540/230513).
- Use the `History View` navigation controls to move among available changes.
- Identify critical revisions in the `Message` column of the `Diff Viewer` pane.
- Check `Options > Team > History` settings to match your workflow.
- Search for `History View` in the help dialog for additional guidance.

Comment: @trashgod--Thanks for encouraging me to dig deeper into the History area of Netbeans. I'd been using it but not with intelligence. You provided BIG HELP!