# cannot right click on Jframe or Jpanel in netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Earlier it was working properly. But all of sudden it stopped responding, whenever I right click on JFrame or JPanel in design mode it doesn't respond. so now I cannot set the layout to null layout by this way.

Comment: *so now I cannot set the layout to null layout by this way.* See [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)

Comment: Check the local [history](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25817867/230513) for the problematic change.