# Netbeans GUI blocked , I can 't add, move or modify components on the JFrame form

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-8

I'm developing an interface for my app with netbeans GUI.

Everything was perfect, I was coding and running the interface with no problems but after the last run the form that I've made was blocked or locked. I don't know, I just can't move or add anything on it and when I right click on any component on the frame there are only two options:

- copy
- properties

When I go to properties, everything is in grey you can't modify anything!

I'm lost I spent lots of hours working on the form and I don't want to start from scratch again!

Comment: It's possible that the form is in "read only" mode for some reason (typically because it can't load some component it relies on).  Try restarting Netbeans, if that fails, delete the cached data from `{user.home}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache` (on Windows) and restart Netbeans.  Also make sure you do a clean and build of the project BEFORE you try loading the forms

Comment: did you externally modify netbeans genarated code?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried to empty the cache multiple times and i did what you told me but in vain

Comment: @FastSnail  no i didn't  :/

Comment: Check the history, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25826065/230513).

Comment: @trashgod  nothing changed the problem is persisting

Comment: problem is solved by copying/pasting all the components on a new form :)